# How do I integrate google sign in with aws cognito?

Tags: typescript, next.js, amazon-cognito, google-signin, next-auth

I'm attempting to integrate a google provider from next-auth with aws cognito. Logging in with cognito works fine, but when I attempt to login with google I get an error on the screen saying "An error was encountered with the requested page. Invalid state" I double checked all of the .env variables so I don't believe that's the problem. The only thing that comes to mind is that the state parameter is being used incorrectly but I really can't tell.

```
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, GetUserCommand, InitiateAuthCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import Facebook from 'next-auth/providers/facebook'
import { COGNIS_BASE_PATH, SOCIAL_REDIRECT_URL } from "@/app/utils/constants";

export const generateRandomString = () => {
    // Implement your logic to generate a random string
    return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}



const googleProvider = Google({
    name: 'Google',
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    authorization: {
        params: {
            client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            redirect_uri: SOCIAL_REDIRECT_URL,
            scope: 'profile email openid',
            // Include the state parameter in the authorization URL
            state: generateRandomString(),
        },
    },
    profile: (profile) => {
        console.log(profile);
        return {
            id: profile.id,
            name: profile.name,
            email: profile.email,
            image: profile.picture,
        }
    }
});
const facebookProvider = Facebook({
    name: 'Facebook',
    clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID as string,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET as string,
    authorization: {
        params: {
            client_id: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID as string,
            redirect_uri: SOCIAL_REDIRECT_URL as string,
            scope: 'public profile email',
        },
    },
});
 
const cognitoProvider = Providers({
    name: 'Cognito',
    credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
    },
    authorize: async (credentials: any) => {
        const { username, password } = credentials;
 
        const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
            region: process.env.COGNITO_REGION,
        });
        try {
            const command = new InitiateAuthCommand({
                AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
                ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID as string,
                AuthParameters: {
                    USERNAME: username,
                    PASSWORD: password,
                },
            });
            const response = await cognitoClient.send(command);
            if (response.AuthenticationResult) {
                 // Retrieve custom attributes
                 const getUserCommand = new GetUserCommand({
                    AccessToken: response.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken
                });
 
                const userResponse = await cognitoClient.send(getUserCommand);
                if (userResponse.UserAttributes) {
                    const customAttributes = userResponse.UserAttributes.filter(attr => attr.Name?.startsWith('custom:'));
                   
                    return {
                        id: username,
                        ...response.AuthenticationResult,
                        customAttributes: customAttributes
                    };
                }else{
                    return {
                        id: username,
                        ...response.AuthenticationResult
                    };
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return null;
        }
    },
});
 
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [cognitoProvider, googleProvider, facebookProvider],
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
            console.log((user as any).AccessToken);
            return true;
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = { ...user as any };
                // console.log((token.user as any).AccessToken);
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (token?.user) {
                session.user = token.user;
            }
            return session
        },
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) { return baseUrl },
    },
    useSecureCookies: false
};

 
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
console.log(generateRandomString())
 
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```